# Writing xyz coordinates in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write the co-ordinates (xyz coordinates) of a double-circle in a csv file.

I have written following code now.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

bLength=2.10e-10
numPoints=10
totalLength = bLength * numPoints
Circumference = totalLength
radius = Circumference / (2 * np.pi)
totalAngle=360.0
angle = 360.0/numPoints

# define a function frange to include fraction
def frange(start, stop, step):
    i = start
    while i < stop:
        yield i
        i += step
# getting the x, y co-ordinates of the two circles displaced by angle/2)    
for i in frange(0.0, 360.0, angle):
    plt.plot(radius * np.cos(i), radius * np.sin(i), 'bo')
    for j in frange(angle/2, 360.0, angle):
        plt.plot(radius * np.cos(j), radius * np.sin(j), 'bo')

plt.show()
```

Here, I get a circle in the graph (in Jupyter Notebook). However, I would like to write the coordinates (xyz) of these circles (double-circle) in a "csv file".

The syntax may be as follow. However, I am not able to proceed further.

```
with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ').writerows(f)
```

The final output should contain three columns. The first two coummns of the csv will come from the above "for loops". The third coloumn of the csv file should be some constant (say 0 or 2.1). How can I do this?

Comment: append to a list, then `np.array(list)`, then use `np.savetxt` to write the array

Comment: You can use numpy array to simplify the code. If you know the radius:
`t = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, granularity)`
`x,y = radius*np.cos(t), radius*np.sin(t)`

Comment: Can you tell us why you have two loops? The outer loop generates a circle, but the inner loop generates one extra circle for every angle in the outer loop! Yet you mention you are plotting "a circle". Do you want one circle or more?

Comment: @anishtain4 I need the coordinates for tow circles separated at a small distance. The second loop is for generating the second circle (at a small distance from first circle).

Comment: @phenomenon No, everything is in the same circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning the math and python a little bit, this should work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bLength=2.10e-10
numPoints=10
radius = bLength*numPoints / (2 * np.pi)
theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,numPoints,endpoint=False)
dtheta=theta[1]-theta[0]
x0,y0=np.cos(theta),np.sin(theta)
x1,y1=np.cos(theta+dtheta/2),np.sin(theta+dtheta/2)
plt.plot(x0,y0)
plt.plot(x1,y1)
cons=np.ones(x0.shape)*10
np.savetxt('circle.csv',np.c_[x0,y0,cons],delimiter=',')
```

in `linspace` function, I've used `endpoint=False` to avoid repetition of the same value, but in plots this makes it look discontinues. You can duplicate it and when packing them to write use `np.c_[x0[:-1],y0[:-1],cons[:-1]]` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the clear code. This produces only half of the coordinates. A model of the double-ring for which I need the xyz coordinates is available here in Figure (a) and (c):  https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-clusters-B-42-presented-as-double-ring-2-21-and-triplering-3-14-upper-The_fig3_262797718.

Comment: @phenomenon: This writes coordinates of "a" circle and a constant as you have mentioned in your question. Do you want both circles? just change the array in `savetxt` to `out_array=np.r_[np.c_[x0,y0,cons0],np.c_[x1,y1,cons1]`.
Changing the code based on what you want should be easy.